# How to use a jar file that has been updated (Using a command line)

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to use a jar file from http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/. I've downloaded the jar file, put it in the CLASSPATH but every time I try to run my program in the command line I get the message "package does not exist".

The jar file is algs4.jar

In the site it says "As of August 17, 2015, the "default package" version of algs4.jar has been replaced with a "named package" version. To access the classes in algs4.jar, you will need to use an import statement like the ones below:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.MinPQ;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
```

"
I think this is the main issue since I don't really understand what they are talking about(This is the first time I'm using a jar file)

The code (Binary Search):

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class BinarySearch
{
    public static int rank(int key, int[] a)
    { // Array must be sorted.
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = a.length - 1;
        while (lo <= hi)
        { // Key is in a[lo..hi] or not present.
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            if (key < a[mid]) hi = mid - 1;
            else if (key > a[mid]) lo = mid + 1;
            else return mid;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int[] whitelist = In.readInts(args[0]);
        Arrays.sort(whitelist);
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
        { // Read key, print if not in whitelist.
            int key = StdIn.readInt();
            if (rank(key, whitelist) < 0)
                StdOut.println(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: 
The command I used: Javac -cp .;edu.princeton.cs.algs4.jar BinarySearch.java

The jar file is algs4.jar not edu.princeton.cs.algs4.jar

Comment: A jar file is a zip file. Open it, and see if you have this package inside. Note that the transition to the new package structure doesn't happen magically. If you have an old jar that doesn't have that structure, you need to download the newer jar. You also need to tell us how you tried compiling and running your code.

Comment: Is the .jar file itself named `algs4.jar` or is the actual file name `edu.princeton.cs.algs4.jar`?

Comment: The jar file is named algs4.jar

In the site it says "As of August 17, 2015, the "default package" version of algs4.jar has been replaced with a "named package" version. To access the classes in algs4.jar, you will need to use an import statement like the ones below:

Comment: If the jar file name is algs4.jar, why do you add edu.princeton.cs.algs4.jar to the classpath option? You're passing the name of a non-exiting file.

Answer (score 0):

Put the jar file in a folder in your project, if you're using Eclipse then in Package explorer locate the jar file, **right click > build path > add to build path**. After that you will be able to use the import statements and compile normally like any other eclipse project. However it gets a bit tricky compiling from terminal/command line.

In that case the best way to compile this would be generating an ANT buildfile in eclipse. You can google generating ANT buildfile and how to compile using ANT.